# Drawing multiple circles on a single line CGGraphicsContext

Tags: swift, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, drawrect, quartz-2d

I have a custom class that manages a custom view that has a horizontal center on screen (which will represent a solid line). And I've drawn the line like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
    let line = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextSetLineWidth(line, 3.0)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(line, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)

            CGContextMoveToPoint(line, 0, self.bounds.midY)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(line, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.midY)

            CGContextStrokePath(line)
  }
```

However, I need to draw a multiple solid circles on this line and try to look it like a point in a chart. I'm trying to make a mini chart representation in fact. How can I draw the circles? With a nested 'for in' loop or? Is there any official chart API from Apple?

Answer (score 1):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` gives you a context that you can draw multiple things into. Calling it `line` is not the right idea, because it can contain multiple lines, or circles, or all sorts of other things.

Think of the context as an artist sitting in front of a blank canvas. You give the artist instructions, like "draw a red line, then draw a blue circle". The artist follows the instructions, and afterwards, you look at the canvas.

Here's how you might draw a line and then a circle.

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Tell the context what stroked paths should look like
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)

    // Draw a single line
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.bounds.midY)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.midY)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // Now draw a circle by filling a path.
    // First, set the fill color:
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)

    // Specify how big the circle is, and where its center is:
    let circleRadius = CGFloat(5.0)
    let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    // Then add a circle to the context, by specifying the rectangle that surrounds it:
    let circleRect = CGRect(x: circleCenter.x - circleRadius,
                            y: circleCenter.y - circleRadius,
                            width: circleRadius * 2,
                            height: circleRadius * 2)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circleRect)

    // And fill that circle:
    CGContextFillPath(context)
```

If you want to draw more circles but in different places, just call `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` and `CGContextFillPath` again, but with different values for `circleRect`. Depending on what you want, a for loop might be appropriate. It's entirely up to you.

If you don't want to write it yourself, there are lots of 3rd-party chart libraries available, just do a search. Apple does not provide an "official" one.